# EF6: Getting a subtree in a hierarchical parent/child model

Tags: c#, mysql, performance, entity-framework

I have a self-associated entity to simulate a hierarchical tree. Every entity an have 0 or 1 parent entities and can have many children entities.

That said, I'm trying to get all the entities starting from an arbitrary node (a subtree).

My attempt:

```
// Get root node
var rootNode = DB.HierarchyNodeSet.Where(x => x.Id == inputNodeId).SingleOrDefault();

// Recursively get all children from this node
IEnumerable<HierarchyNode> subTreeNodes = RecursiveGetNodeChildren(rootNode);
```

With `RecursiveGetNodeChildren()` coded like this:

```
private IEnumerable<HierarchyNode> RecursiveGetNodeChildren(HierarchyNode n)
{
    List<HierarchyNode> lsOut = new List<HierarchyNode>();
    lsOut.Add(n);
    if (n.Children.Any())
        foreach (var child in n.Children)
            lsOut.AddRange(RecursiveGetNodeChildren(child));

    return lsOut;
}
```

This works, but it is too slow (I have ~10k nodes).

To get the root node I spend 5-7 secs, that is acceptable to me, but the recursive routine takes more than 30 secs.

I think I'm taking the problem from a wrong perspective. Any of you can suggest (if one exists) a best practise to get hierarchical data in a faster way?

Thank you in advance

F.

Comment: Take a look at the nested set model. It's more work setting up and when you insert/remove items, but retrieving data is super fast.

Comment: Have you tested the performance with a release build? 5 - 7 seconds for the first retrieval (assuming that `Id` is the primary key), is not likely unless there is a ton of other things happening under the hood.

Comment: @DavidG this code is part of a backend of a website, and the hierarchy could be updated very often as far as we can predict. The nested set model could be counterproductive.
@KeithPayne yes, the `Id` is a PK. I simplified that specific instruction just to focus on the recursive routine (which I think is the real problem), but the `rootNode` retrieve instruction has a bit more complex Where-clause ( `DB.HierarchyNodeSet.Where(x => x.Hierarchy.Id == hierarchyId && x.Id == inputNodeId).SingleOrDefault()` )

Comment: @silentman.it I thought it was worth mentioning as 5-7 seconds seems pretty nasty, let alone 30 seconds. I've done similar routines like this before over tens of thousands of nodes and not seen it take that long. Is it making database queries for every recursive call? As a minor improvement, you can remove the `if` statement.

Comment: Hmmmm... How can I make sure that no SQL query is done in the recursive routine?